# form.reset with to a new initial values, is not enables onSubmit button in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-final-form

I am setting new initial values and when clicking on the "Reset" button the "Submit" button doesn't become enabled.
First I am initializing the form with data from DB and then I am trying to "Reset" these data with new initialized data, then the "Submit" button doesn't become enabled, and both stay disabled.
How can I enable the "Save" button again?
I thought about using the "dirty" prop, but it acts differently than the "pristine" prop.

```
           <StyledActionsButtons>
              <StyledResetButton
                disabled={submitting || pristine}
                onClick={() => {
                  form.reset({
                    tag: i18n.t('settings.detected'),
                    subject:
                      type === 'stop'
                        ? i18n.t('settings.stop')
                        : i18n.t('settings.stoppingBy'),
                    title:
                      type === 'stop'
                        ? i18n.t(
                            'settings.stopper'
                          )
                        : i18n.t('settings.stepForward')
                  });
                }}
              >
                {i18n.t('settings.reset')}
              </StyledResetButton>
              <StyledButton
                primary={0}
                htmlType="submit"
                disabled={submitting || pristine || readOnly}
              >
                {i18n.t('settings.save')}
              </StyledButton>
            </StyledActionsButtons>
```

Help is appreciated.
Tom

Comment: I think some more code would be helpful. Did you tried console.log the readOnly value? As there is a || statement if one of them is true disabled will be true for submit button. Try console logging each variable. And see what is going on.

Comment: tried and everything is working as expected. "pristine" becomes 'true' when I reinitialize the form data, therefore the "disabled" becomes 'true'. I don't know how to reinitialize and set the "Submit" button to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the pristine flag is true if you don't make any changes.  I'm not sure what your are trying to accomplish, but it doesn't seem like you want to reset initial values but set fields to a know value and submit.  To set form state, use a [mutator](https://medium.com/@erikras/final-form-arrays-and-mutators-13159cb7d285).